# How to open one single popup window for multiple onclick event of anchor tag?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have one aspx page with 1000 anchor tag.

I want to open single popup onclick of anchor tag & display data in popup window from database dynamically.

I want to use only one popup in my page.

For 1000 anchor tag inner data of popup will change with respect to anchor click change.

```
<h5><a  href="#" runat="server" >Advertise & Media</a>
   <em>
2 entries
   </em>
</h5>
<ol>
   <li><a id="advMedia1" runat="server" href="#" onclick="advMedia1_onclick">Advertise Agency</a></li>
   <li><a runat="server" runat="server" href="#">Magazine</a></li>
   <li><a runat="server" runat="server" href="#">Press</a></li>
   <li><a runat="server" runat="server" href="#">Weekly</a></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: There are a few ways of doing this, using asp.net ajax modalpopupextender or jquery.  Are you able to use either of these?  Also, this is a very basic fundamental thing using anchor targets.

Comment: Yess im using modalpopupextender..but it give problem to open click event in .cs file.

Comment: You will have to post some code then.

Comment: @marc_s i edited question.plz see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `window.open()` function accepts the name of the window as the second parameter.

```
window.open(url, name);
```

When you already have a popup window with the same name open, your browser will reuse that window.

So for example

```
window.open('/Page1.aspx', 'SameWindow');
window.open('/Page2.aspx', 'SameWindow');
window.open('/Page3.aspx', 'SameWindow');
window.open('/Page4.aspx', 'SameWindow');
```

These will all open in the same window.

Comment: thanks for reply but i have 100 anchor tag within single page. i want to open small popup on click of anchor tag.& fetch data from different table with respect to anchor tag. As anchor change data within popup will be change.

Comment: Are you using server side onclick events?

Answer (score 0):

you could try to update the data for your popup panel